# Grouping MySQL query by date range and productId

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to alter my sql code (see below for screenshot of current results + sql) to group the data by the month AND sum up all the paymentSplitAmounts.  Each row should be a unique productId

So the end result would be something like

```
    productID        total        month
    1                500          11-2011
    2                650          11-2011
    3                250          11-2011
    1                100          10-2011
    2                150          10-2011
    3                750          10-2011
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right.  Where am I going wrong?

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8xzP.jpg

```
    select  
        cpd.paymentId, cpd.paymentId, cpd.productId, cpd.paymentSplitAmount, cp.campaignId, cp.paymentDate 
    from campaign_payment_detail cpd 
    inner join 
        campaign_payment cp on cp.paymentId = cpd.paymentId 
    inner join product on cpd.productId = product.productId 
    where 
    1=1 
    and cp.campaignId = 2413
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to group then sort your results:

```
SELECT cpd.productId, SUM(cpd.paymentSplitAmount), DATE_FORMAT(cp.paymentDate, '%b-%Y')
  FROM campaign_payment_detail cpd
  JOIN campaign_payment cp ON cp.paymentId = cpd.paymentId
  JOIN product ON cpd.productId = product.productId
 WHERE cp.campaignId = 2413
 GROUP BY cpd.productId, DATE_FORMAT(cp.paymentDate, '%b-%Y')
 ORDER BY cp.paymentDate DESC, cpd.productId ASC
```

edit: Using DATE_FORMAT to format the date like you want.

Comment: We have a winner!  Thanks so much this was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

First, based on the query you provided and without other information, the table product is useless..

I will do that:

```
select  
        cpd.paymentId,
        SUM(cpd.paymentSplitAmount) as total, 
        cp.campaignId, 
        cp.paymentDate 
    from campaign_payment_detail cpd 
    inner join 
        campaign_payment cp on cp.paymentId = cpd.paymentId 
    where 
    cp.campaignId = 2413
GROUP BY cpd.productId, cp.paymentDate
ORDER BY cpd.paymentId ASC, cp.paymentDate DESC
```

Comment: This is REALLY close. 
http://imgur.com/O35M7,Ts7YD,FKqOm#1

Especially if you add productId to the select statement.  the problem is that it's only showing data for october and omitting the data for january.

Comment: I don't know how is your table structure, try to readd the inner join I removed... :)

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned 'grouping'. For that you need to add `group by` to your query, to group the data by productid and month, then you can add `sum` to sum the paymentSplitAmount.

The grouping syntax isn't wrong, it is missing completely. :)

```
select  
    cpd.productId, sum(cpd.paymentSplitAmount) as total, date_format(cp.paymentDate, '%m-%Y')
from campaign_payment_detail cpd 
inner join campaign_payment cp on cp.paymentId = cpd.paymentId 
inner join product on cpd.productId = product.productId 
where 
  cp.campaignId = 2413
group by cp.productId, date_format(cp.paymentDate, '%m-%Y')
order by date_format(cp.paymentDate, '%m-%Y') desc, cp.productId
```

<strike>This assumes cp.paymentDate already contains the months. If not, you will have to round each date to the first of the month and group by that.</strike>

Now groups by month.

Comment: http://imgur.com/O35M7,Ts7YD,FKqOm#0

This doesn't produce the desired results. :(

Comment: That's because of grouping the months, like I told you in my last sentence. See edit.